# Squid and delay pools: rep_mime_type, https

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm struggling with squid delay pools. The documentation I found is very poor and on internet there is contradictory and possibly surpassed information.

First question:

- acl aclname url_regex -i \.exe

will it match an HTTPS request ? According to my experience and from some posts it will not, so cannot find any easy way to limit the bandwidth used to download **.exe** files from an **HTTPS** connection. Am I missing something ?

Second question:

- acl streaming_exe rep_mime_type application/octet-stream

Can **rep_mime_type** be used with **delay_access poolNumber allow** ?
Again, according to my experience and to some very old posts in internet it will not work, but the documentation lacks this important limitation.

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 0):

An answer received in the squid mailing list confirms all my doubts:

> "HTTPS" is not a single thing, or message type. It is a term to describe
>   an entire stack of multiple-layered protocols.
>
> To do anything at all with URL or any other HTTP message details in what
>   could be termed an "HTTPS request" requires decrypting the TLS layer to
>   find the HTTP message secured inside it.
>
> ItFrom that description it sounds to me like you are dealing with a
>   plain-text HTTP message of method CONNECT. There is almost zero
>   information in those. Apart from the domain name of the server the
>   client wants to talk to and maybe the client UA device, you are out of
>   luck using any of the more normal request/reply message details to
>   decide on the pool.
>
> Squid should still be able to delay pool those CONNECT tunnels though.
>   But only as a whole thing, and there are still open bugs with unknown
>   causes. You need a fairly recent version of Squid for it to work even
>   halfway close to "properly".
>
> For bandwidth control it is often better to use the QoS / TOS
>   functionality provided by your OS. Squid can output per-request values
>   for those systems to work with using qos_flows, tcp_outgoing_tos or
>   tcp_outgoing_mark.

And about the second question:

> Of the current Squid only 4.0.2 or later can do that. (re-)assiging
>   pools based on HTTP response details was only very recently ported from
>   Squid-2.6.